# javascript/php for loop not working?

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

My phpcode is

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>
  <div class="upperBoxContainer" id="test1<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
    <a href="#"><img id="test<?php echo $i; ?>" src="images/midimages/<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg"></a>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And my javascript code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        alert('images/midimageshover/' + i + '.jpg');
        $('#test1' + i).hover(function() {
            $('#test' + i).attr('src', 'images/midimageshover/' + i + '.jpg');
        });
        $('#test1' + i).mouseout(function() {
            $('#test' + i).attr('src', 'images/midimages/' + i + '.jpg');
        });
    }
});
```

There is some error due to this code is not work. can you please find this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least provide the error message

Comment: dude, for me the code looks no logical errors, but in place of .hover use .mouseover $('#test1'+i).mouseover (function(){...

Comment: It'd be much easier to just attach the event handler to the `upperBoxContainer` and grab the value of `$i` using jQuery

Comment: Please provide some form of error message so we can help debug the code.

Comment: thanks to all! bug removed by Jonathan de M.'s solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your events in a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {  
    (function(i){
      $('#test1'+i).hover(function(){
        $('#test' + i).attr('src', 'images/midimageshover/' + i + '.jpg');
      });
      $('#test1'+i).mouseout(function(){
        $('#test' + i).attr('src', 'images/midimages/' + i + '.jpg');
      });
    })(i);
  }
});
```

Your code is rewriting the value of `$('#test1'+i)` until it reaches 4, so at the end of the loop you'll only have `$('#test14')`.

The code above create different scope by using the IIFE hence `$('#test1'+i)` won't be overwritten, instead you'll have `$('#test11')`, `$('#test12')`, `$('#test13')`, `$('#test14')`

[Here is a demo to demonstrate the difference with your initial code](http://jsbin.com/obuvag/2/edit)

Comment: +1 didn't realise you had to wrap a loop like that in a function, but I guess if I'm using jquery I wouldn't have done a for loop so have never come across this problem